# NSInteger is NSInteger error

Tags: objective-c

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender{
  If (cardsinplay >= 16){
    NSNumber *cardValue = carsAndValue[14];
    NSInteger *Value = [cardValue integerValue[;
```

From what i know this should read the NSNumber from the array and change it into a NSInteger
But i get this error.

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion initialization 'NSInteger*'(aka 'int*') with an expression of type 'NSInteger'(aka 'int*')
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Oh, and why don't you 1. read and understand the error message, 2. look up the definition of the types you are using in the documentation before actually using them?

Answer (score 4):

`-[NSNumber integerValue]` returns a `NSInteger`, not a pointer to one.

```
NSInteger *Value = [cardValue integerValue];
```

should be

```
NSInteger value = [cardValue integerValue];
```